# Bivariate structured interpolation of large array with NaN values or mask

Tags: python, dictionary, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate regularly gridded [windstress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_stress) data using Scipy's [RectBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) class. At some grid points, the input data contains invalid data entries, which are set to NaN values. To start with, I used the solution to [Scott's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146025/python-scipy-2d-interpolation-non-uniform-data) on bidimensional interpolation. Using my data, the interpolation returns an array containing only NaNs. I have also tried a different approach assuming my data is unstructured and using the [SmoothBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline) class. Apparently I have too many data points to use unstructured interpolation, since the shape of the data array is (719 x 2880).

To illustrate my problem I created the following script:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import pylab

from scipy import interpolate


# The signal and lots of noise
M, N = 20, 30  # The shape of the data array
y, x = numpy.mgrid[0:M+1, 0:N+1]
signal = -10 * numpy.cos(x / 50 + y / 10) / (y + 1)
noise = numpy.random.normal(size=(M+1, N+1))
z = signal + noise


# Some holes in my dataset
z[1:2, 0:2] = numpy.nan
z[1:2, 9:11] = numpy.nan
z[0:1, :12] = numpy.nan
z[10:12, 17:19] = numpy.nan


# Interpolation!
Y, X = numpy.mgrid[0.125:M:0.5, 0.125:N:0.5]
sp = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(y[:, 0], x[0, :], z)
Z = sp(Y[:, 0], X[0, :])

sel = ~numpy.isnan(z)
esp = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(y[sel], x[sel], z[sel], 0*z[sel]+5)
eZ = esp(Y[:, 0], X[0, :])


# Comparing the results
pylab.close('all')
pylab.ion()

bbox = dict(edgecolor='w', facecolor='w', alpha=0.9)
crange = numpy.arange(-15., 16., 1.)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax.contourf(x, y, z, crange)
ax.set_title('Original')
ax.text(0.05, 0.98, 'a)', ha='left', va='top', transform=ax.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

bx = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
bx.contourf(X, Y, Z, crange)
bx.set_title('Spline')
bx.text(0.05, 0.98, 'b)', ha='left', va='top', transform=bx.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)

cx = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3, sharex=ax, sharey=ax)
cx.contourf(X, Y, eZ, crange)
cx.set_title('Expected')
cx.text(0.05, 0.98, 'c)', ha='left', va='top', transform=cx.transAxes, 
    bbox=bbox)
```

Which gives the following results:[image: Bivariate gridding. (a) The original constructed data, (b) Scipy's RectBivariateSpline and (c) SmoothBivariateSpline classes.]

The figure shows a constructed data map (a) and the results using Scipy's RectBivariateSpline (b) and SmoothBivariateSpline (c) classes. The first interpolation results in an array with only NaNs. Ideally I would have expected a result similar to the second interpolation, which is more computationally intensive. I don't necessarily need data extrapolation outside of the domain region.

Comment: You cannot do structured interpolation with missing data. If unstructured interpolation is also not an option, you could try to break up your domain into rectangular chunks, then do unstructured interpolation wherever there is missing data, and structured everywhere else. If you were using linear interpolation, then partitioning your domain would be your only problem. But if you are using third degree splines, then you also need to take care of the boundary conditions between your chunks, which I am not sure how to go about.

Comment: You can also give `scipy.interpolate.griddata` a shoot, similarly to smoothbivariatespline.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `griddata`, the only problem being that it doesn't handle the edges well. This could be helped by for instance reflecting, depending on how your data is...
Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy
import pylab
from scipy import interpolate


# The signal and lots of noise
M, N = 20, 30  # The shape of the data array
y, x = numpy.mgrid[0:M+1, 0:N+1]
signal = -10 * numpy.cos(x / 50 + y / 10) / (y + 1)
noise = numpy.random.normal(size=(M+1, N+1))
z = signal + noise


# Some holes in my dataset
z[1:2, 0:2] = numpy.nan
z[1:2, 9:11] = numpy.nan
z[0:1, :12] = numpy.nan
z[10:12, 17:19] = numpy.nan

zi = numpy.vstack((z[::-1,:],z))
zi = numpy.hstack((zi[:,::-1], zi))
y, x = numpy.mgrid[0:2*(M+1), 0:2*(N+1)]
y *= 5 # anisotropic interpolation if needed.

zi = interpolate.griddata((y[~numpy.isnan(zi)], x[~numpy.isnan(zi)]),
                zi[~numpy.isnan(zi)], (y, x), method='cubic')
zi = zi[:(M+1),:(N+1)][::-1,::-1]

pylab.subplot(1,2,1)
pylab.imshow(z, origin='lower')
pylab.subplot(1,2,2)
pylab.imshow(zi, origin='lower')
pylab.show()
```

If you run out of memory, you could split your data, along the lines of:

```
def large_griddata(data_x, vals, grid, method='nearest'):
    x, y = data_x
    X, Y = grid
    try:
        return interpolate.griddata((x,y),vals,(X,Y),method=method)
    except MemoryError:
        pass

    N = (np.min(X)+np.max(X))/2.
    M = (np.min(Y)+np.max(Y))/2.

    masks = [(x<N) & (y<M),
             (x<N) & (y>=M),
             (x>=N) & (y<M),
             (x>=N) & (y>=M)]

    grid_mask = [(X<N) & (Y<M),
             (X<N) & (Y>=M),
             (X>=N) & (Y<M),
             (X>=N) & (Y>=M)]

    Z = np.zeros_like(X)
    for i in range(4):
        Z[grid_mask[i]] = large_griddata((x[masks[i]], y[masks[i]]),
                    vals[masks[i]], (X[grid_mask[i]], Y[grid_mask[i]]), method=method)

    return Z
```