# How to mask data in scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline

Tags: python, scipy, gis, spatial-interpolation, data-masking

I have some curvilinear gridded data, and I'm trying to interpolate this data to a new grid. The data has unrealistically high variables for the masked data, so I tried masking using:

```
temp = np.ma.masked_where(temp > 500, temp)
```

if I do this then:

```
>>> temp.max()
28.174417
```

However, when I run:

```
temp = RectBivariateSpline(lon, lat,
                           np.swapaxes(temp, 0, 1))
temp = temp.ev(newgrid_lon, newgrid_lat)
```

I end up with the unrealistically high mask values again:

```
>>> temp.max()
1.541312613999187e+30
```

`scipy.interpolate` is obviously not accepting my mask. Does anyone know how to set a mask for `scipy.interpolate` or know any workarounds? Thanks.

Comment: Fundamentally you can't do structured interpolation with missing data ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15485343/1461210)). You could either treat your data as unstructured (e.g. exclude the masked values and use `SmoothBivariateSpline` instead of `RectBivariateSpline`), or else replace your masked values with some sort of approximation (the mean of their nearest neighbours? a constant?) before doing your interpolation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I may try setting the masked values to a constant as you suggest. I will see how that makes the data look. If that doesn't work, I might have to look into `SmoothBivariateSpline`. I just hope its not as slow as `griddata`.

Comment: It worked well enough for my purposes. Thanks.

Comment: `np.ma` just adds the mask array without actually changing the data array.  Only the `np.ma` methods/functions take the mask into account.  Other `numpy` and `scipy` code just uses the data without awareness of the mask.

Comment: I found a great solution using `pyresample.kd_tree.resample_gauss`. It is mask aware, customizable, and very fast. I will be using this for all my grid interpolation in the future.