Interpolating from 2D table in python
I have X,Y and Z columns of data (pandas data frame). I then create a 2D table from it like below with some spaced "X_Axis" and "Y_Axis" of the table.
X = Reference_Data['Spd']
Y = Reference_Data['Tq']
X_Axis = np.linspace(500, 2200, 18)
Y_Axis = np.linspace(0, 2800, 29)
Z = Reference_Data['Position']
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(X_Axis, Y_Axis)
zi = griddata((X,Y),Z,(xi,yi),method='cubic')

Now I want to interpolate values from the 2d table for any given x and y values pairs (as example shown below), preferably spline interpolation.



Xi
Yi




1082.5
336.2917


1076
301.58356


1060.5
1031.8756





(1) What is your question? (2) Are you looking to interpolate or extrapolate? (3) Please provide example data for a [mre].

Have you tried RectBivariateSpline?

I tried but it gives me NAN value. I came across this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572743/to-do-a-spline-surface-fit-using-scipys-rectbivariatespline-and-smoothbivariate". In short I still don't have solution.

I missed the first question. I am trying to interpolate.
