# Construct NumPy matrix row by row

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I'm trying to construct a 2D NumPy array from values in an extant 2D NumPy array using an iterative process.  Using ordinary python lists the process I'm describing would look like so:

```
coords = #data from file contained in a 2D list
d = #integer
edges = []
for i in range(d+1):
    for j in range(i+1, d+1):
        edge = coords[j] - coords[i]
        edges.append(edge)
```

However, the NumPy array imposes restrictions that do not permit the process shown above.  Below I try to do the same thing using NumPy arrays, and it should immediately be clear where the problems are:

```
coords = np.genfromtxt('Energies.txt', dtype=float, skip_header=1)
d = #integer
#how to initialize?
for i in range(d+1):
    for j in range(i+1, d+1):
        edge = coords[j] - coords[i]
        #how to append?
```

Because .append does not exist for NumPy arrays I need to rely on concatenate or stack instead.  But these functions are designed to join existing arrays, and I don't have anything to concatenate or stack until after the first iteration of my loop.  So I suppose I need to change my data flow, but I'm unsure how to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not stick with your first code, and then do `edges_arr = np.asarray(edges)`?

Comment: Because then I have to parse my coordinate file manually, instead of using numpy.genfromtxt.  Moreover, I will have to do calculations involving values from both my edges array and the coords array, so I want to be consistent with my containers.

Comment: Well, we will need a [mcve] with reproducible code and output that makes it clear what you're trying to do. What you have now is incomplete code and a request to fix it.

Comment: There are two reasonable ways of building arrays iteratively.  1) create the array from the list, 2) initialize an `zeros` array of the right size, and set 'row' values iteratively.  Don't try to squeeze arrays into the list model.

Comment: `coords` is a (m,n) array.  Looks like you want to take all the differences between rows, producing a (m,m,n) array.  The only special thing is that you are trying to avoid duplicates, and get just the upper (or lower) triangle of values.

Answer (score 1):

that function is numpy.meshgrid [1] , the function does it by default.

[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for.   That function returns a coordinate matrix from a set of coordinate vectors.  I already have a matrix, representing a set of points in space that do not fit to a grid, and I want the set of non-redundant vectors that can be constructed from those points.

Comment: You search something similar to
scipy.interpolate.interp2d

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49478006/9799449