# Searching for interpolated data from a pandas multi-index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, interpolation, multi-index

I have established a multi-index `pandas` dataframe as per below:

```
import pandas as pd
GEN_power_vs_PF_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('GEN PF', '0.85'),
                                                   ('GEN PF', '0.9'),
                                                   ('GEN PF', '0.95'),
                                                   ('GEN PF', '1.0')])

GEN_power_vs_PF_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Generator power at terminal, (kW)', 201875),
                                                     ('Generator power at terminal, (kW)', 403750),
                                                     ('Generator power at terminal, (kW)', 605625),
                                                     ('Generator power at terminal, (kW)', 807500),
                                                     ('Generator power at terminal, (kW)', 1009375)])

GEN_power_vs_PF = pd.DataFrame([(3217.6, 4259.1, 5847, 8024.1, 11059.1),
                                (3133.2, 4023, 5390.5, 7242.6, 9678.4),
                                (3045.4, 3791.7, 4954.4, 6538.8, 8564),
                                (2891.6, 3439.5, 4346.6, 5609.6, 7228.9)],
                               index=GEN_power_vs_PF_index,
                               columns=GEN_power_vs_PF_columns)
```

How do I search for an interpolated value from the dataframe, e.g. for a `GEN PF` value of 0.9769 and `Generator power at terminal, (kW)` of 736381.3?

I'm fairly new to `pandas`, and so far I've tried using the `df.loc` method, which is only good for looking up readily available data (without interpolation), and even then I wasn't able to perform a 2D search. I kept getting a `Key Error`.

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772218/fastest-way-to-use-numpy-interp-on-a-2-d-array), pandas dataframe can be converted to numpy array.

Comment: When you search, what do want the output to be? The index value and column name for the closest cell? Or the interpolated cell value?

Comment: How big will your actual dataframe be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124235/2901002):

```
from scipy import interpolate
x = GEN_power_vs_PF.index.get_level_values(1).astype(float)
y = GEN_power_vs_PF.columns.get_level_values(1)
z = GEN_power_vs_PF.to_numpy()
# you have to set kx and ky small for this small example dataset
# 3 is more usual and is the default
# s=0 will ensure this interpolates.  s>0 will smooth the data
# you can also specify a bounding box outside the data limits
# if you want to extrapolate
sp = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, z, kx=2, ky=2, s=0)

print (sp([0.9769], [736381.3]))
[[5528.38273829]]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help; this had helped to partially solve my problem.